# Find non-singular solution to the following ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

was wondering for a while how to solve it but couldn't reach to a conclusion.
Any help would be appreciated.

**Question :** Given ODE
$$y' = \frac{y}{x}f\left(\frac{y}{x^3}\right)$$
Find the singular and the non singular solutions.
(What is the requirement on $f$ to exist such a solution ?).

**My try :**
Singular solutions : $y=0$
when $f(t)=0$ for some $t\in \mathbb{R}$
existence of solution : by Picard's theorem for unique solution -
$$\frac {y}{x}f\left(\frac{y}{x^3}\right) \quad , \quad \frac{1}{x}f\left(\frac{y}{x^3}\right) + \frac{y}{x^4}f'_y\left(\frac{y}{x^3}\right)$$
Needs to be continuous functions.
Here I'm stuck - can't find a concrete restriction of $f$ and can't find a general solution to the ODE.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Try taking the substitutions $y=x^3u$ and $x=\exp(\xi)$.

Comment: @EliBartlett Your suggestion works. But the second substitution must be $y =  \exp (\xi)$

Comment: Is there a different way to solve it ?